# Cast value without changing underlying bits

Tags: c++, c++20

I while ago I googled this, came up with nothing, and had to resort to casting pointers which is a bit clunckly:

```cpp
constexpr float value = 205.5f;
const auto float_as_unsigned =*((uint32_t*)&value);
```

I just realised you could do this with unions:

```cpp
union bit_cast32
{
    float f32;
    uint32_t u32;
    int32_t i32;
};
const auto float_as_unsigned2 = bit_cast32( 205.5f ).u32;
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: "_which is a bit clunckly_": The first variant is undefined behavior per standard and compilers do actually miscompile it without the `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag. The second variant is also undefined behavior in C++, but because it is allowed in C, compilers tend to allow it. The standard-permitted pre-C++20 approach is to `memcpy` between two objects of the corresponding types.

Comment: To avoid UB you generally have to go through `memcpy` for such conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes new to c++20 there is [std::bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast)

```cpp
constexpr auto float_as_unsigned3 = std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(205.5f);
```

Comment: You shouldn't provide the last template argument. It is supposed to be deduced from the argument. Providing it can only result in an accidental conversion, ruining the bit cast. Before c++20 you can also use `std::memcpy` but you need to check yourself that the size of the types match.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thanks I was wondering why the template parameters where ordered in that way.